# HiveError: The box "user" is already open and of type Box<User>

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I'm trying to use `Hive` inside flutter `Mobx`, after checking user data in `Hive` I switched to another screens such as `HomeView` or `Intro`

`main.dart`:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  ...

  final appDocumentDirectory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(UserAdapter());

  _setUpLogging();

  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: providers, child: StartupApplication()));
}
```

`StartupApplication` class: I don't use `Hive`

```
class StartupApplication extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isPlatformDark = WidgetsBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness == Brightness.dark;
    final initTheme = isPlatformDark ? nebrassLightTheme : nebrassLightTheme;
    return ThemeProvider(
      initTheme: initTheme,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
      child: Builder(builder: (context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'TEST',
          theme: ThemeProvider.of(context),
          home: const OverlaySupport(child: OKToast(
           child: MyHomePage() //--> checking user data widget
          )),
          onGenerateRoute: Routes.sailor.generator(),
          navigatorKey: Routes.sailor.navigatorKey,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

checking `User` in `Hive` inside `MyHomePage` class:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder<Box<User>>(
            future: Hive.openBox('user'),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                final Box<User> userBox = snapshot.data;
    
                if (userBox.values.isNotEmpty && userBox.get(0).active == 1) {
                  return HomeView();
                } else {
                  return Intro();
                }
              } else {
                return Container();
              }
            });
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        Hive.close();
        super.dispose();
      }
    }
```

now in other screen such as `RegisterScreen` class I implemented `MobX` and inside that I want to use `user` box, for example:

```
class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  TextEditingController _mobileNumber;

  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldState = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _mobileNumber = TextEditingController();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _registerViewModel = Provider.of<RegisterViewModel>(context, listen: false);

    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldState,

        ...
        //_registerViewModel.registerAccount(_mobileNumber.text, '111');

      ),
    );
  }

  void _showSnackBar(String message, BuildContext context) {
    _scaffoldState.currentState.showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        content: Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
            child: Text(
              '$message',
              style: AppTheme.of(context).caption().copyWith(color: Colors.white),
            ))));
  }
}
```

`MobX` implementation:

```
enum RegisterLoadingState { loading, done }
enum ActiveLoadingState { loading, done }
enum RegisteringState { initial, registered, activated, registerError, activeError }

class RegisterViewModel = _RegisterViewModel with _$RegisterViewModel;

abstract class _RegisterViewModel with Store {
  final WebApi _webApi;

  _RegisterViewModel({@required WebApi webApi}) : _webApi = webApi;

  ...

  @action
  Future<void> registerAccount(String mobileNumber, String deviceId) async {
    final RegisterRequest _request = RegisterRequest(mobileNumber, deviceId);
    try {
      loadingState = RegisterLoadingState.loading;
      final _res = await _webApi.register(_request);
      loadingState = RegisterLoadingState.done;

      _registerResponse = RegisterResponse.fromJson(_res.body as Map<String, dynamic>);

      /* I GET ERROR IN THIS LINE -- HiveError: The box "user" is already open and of type Box<User>.*/

      final userBox = await Hive.openBox('user');
      final user = User(/*...*/);
      userBox.putAt(0, user);
  }

  @action
  Future<void> activeAccount(String mobileNumber, String verifyCode) async {
    final ActiveAccountRequest _activeAccount = ActiveAccountRequest(mobileNumber, verifyCode);

    final userBox = await Hive.openBox('user');
    final User currentUser = userBox.getAt(0) as User;
    final user = User(/*...*/);
    userBox.putAt(0, user);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are opening multiple `boxes` of the same type `User`. What is the question here ?

Comment: @void my question is how can i use previously opened box? i want to use box on different screens or how can i open again box?

Comment: You can open a `Box` in the `main` method of your app and access a `Box` like => `Box userBox = Hive.box('user');`

Comment: @void and how about after that? my mean is `MyHomePage` class

Comment: I added an answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can open your `user` Box in the `main` method of your app:

```
Future<void> main() async {
  ...

  final appDocumentDirectory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(UserAdapter());
  // open the user box
  await Hive.openBox('user');

  _setUpLogging();

  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: providers, child: StartupApplication()));
}
```

2. Access the previously opened box like below:

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // user box
  Box userBox;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // get the previously opened user box
    userBox = Hive.box('user');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // check for your conditions 
    return (userBox.values.isNotEmpty && userBox.get(0).active == 1)
        ? HomeView()
        : Intro();
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i use `FutureBuilder` instead of opening box in `main` function?

Comment: If you want to use the `FutureBuilder` widget in the `HomePage`, you can move the opening of box from `main` to the `HomePage` and use a `FutureBuilder` widget. @DolDurma

Comment: Did you come across any other issues with my provided answer ?

Comment: I changed code and I don't get error now. But I don't want opening box in main function

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, you can move opening of `box` to `HomePage` and use a `FutureBuilder` widget. @DolDurma

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220717/discussion-between-doldurma-and-void).

Answer (score 9):

I've given Hive the first try and observing this.

If you open the box like this:

```
await Hive.openBox("MyModelBox");
```

It'll throw the exception:

```
Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?
```

Let's take a look in `Box`:

```
BoxBase<E> _getBoxInternal<E>(String name, [bool? lazy]) {
    var lowerCaseName = name.toLowerCase();
    var box = _boxes[lowerCaseName];
    if (box != null) {
      if ((lazy == null || box.lazy == lazy) && box.valueType == E) {
        return box as BoxBase<E>;
      } else {
        var typeName = box is LazyBox
            ? 'LazyBox<${box.valueType}>'
            : 'Box<${box.valueType}>';
        throw HiveError('The box "$lowerCaseName" is already open '
            'and of type $typeName.');
      }
    } else {
      throw HiveError('Box not found. Did you forget to call Hive.openBox()?');
    }
  }
```

The `box.valueType` would be `dynamic`,
the `E` would be your class model type `MyModel`. Thus they won't be equal.

But if you passing the particular type of model

```
await Hive.openBox<MyModel>("MyModelBox");
```

The error vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you have already defined another box with type User somewhere with the same name (using

```dart
final myBoxName = 'userBox';
Hive.openBox<User>(myBoxName);
```

and trying to open the box with the same name with another type
e.g.

```
Hive.openBox<bool>(myBoxName);
```

So ofcourse flutter will have problem openning the box, as it is already there with another type.

You have to find where you are using different types & fix the problem by using different names.