# Flutter Hive error box already open when running

Tags: flutter

I have an error like in the picture. Every time I run debug I always get the same error, I've removed all code calling Hive except dependencies. How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: i have done it, `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` but not working @YeasinSheikh

Comment: As for the error, it is coming from cache, since you've removed the package from pubspec.yaml and its code, `flutter clean` would have solved. Try restarting the IDE after `flutte clean`

Comment: Done. but if I call Hive again, the same error will appear

Comment: Can you try [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63660799/10157127)

Comment: Run this code before you start using Hive again..
 await Hive.deleteBoxFromDisk('lowerCaseName');

Comment: problem solved, I deleted hive-2.2.3 cache folder in my locale, and it can run normally again

Comment: but I don't know the name of the box that has been opened @SiddiqueThanikad